# Problem with the redirections of apprequest in php

Tags: facebook

I am using the code below to send an app request to someone.

It works fine; it displays in  Facebook notification.

when I click that notification, it redirects to the facebook app page.

I'm unable to make it redirect to the page which exists list of facbook app requests.

How do I make it redirect there?

is there any need to do changes in my facebook app setting ?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
function FacebookIframeAuthenticator(){
       window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId: '123456789',
            status: true,
            logging: false,
            cookie: false,
            xfbml: true
          });
          FB.Canvas.setSize({height: 2000});
          FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
          FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
        };
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}
new FacebookIframeAuthenticator();
function  sendInvReq ( friendUid, event ){
  FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'I\'d like you to join my professional network on SITE NAME .- DB',
    to: friendUid,
    data: ''
  }
 , function(r){
      if (r != null && typeof(r) != 'undefined'){
        if (r.request_ids){

          FB.api('/me/apprequests/?request_ids='+toString(request_ids));
          $.ajax({
            url: 'http://exapmple.com',
            cache:false,
            type:'POST',
            data:({requestIds: r.request_ids.join(','), x_csrf: csrf}),
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function(transport){}
          });         
        }
      }
    }
 );
}
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by apprequest page?

Answer (score 1):

in your developers page (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/your_app_id/advanced) you must change your application advanced settings "Upgrade to Requests 2.0" to disable

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right: you can't control the notification url. It will always automatically redirect to your app url with one or more `request_ids` as paramter. The only possibility to redirect to your prefered destination is to look for this parameter and react properly.

Comment: but this type of functionality is working properly in branchout.  How they are doing that?